# logLik.lm(): Why does R use (p + 1) instead of p for degree of freedom?

Tags: r, regression, glm, lm, information-theory

I am trying to understand the results from AIC/BIC in R. For some reason R adds 1 to the number of parameters to be estimated. Hence R uses a different formula than `2 * p - 2 * logLik` (in Gaussian case `logLik` is residual sum of squares). In fact it uses: `2 * (p + 1) - 2 * logLik`.

After a research, I found the problem is related to `stats:::logLik.lm()`.

```
> stats:::logLik.lm  ## truncated R function body
## ...
##     attr(val, "df") <- p + 1
## ...
```

As a real example (using R's built-in dataset `trees`), consider:

```
x <- lm(Height ~ Girth, trees)  ## a model with 2 parameters
logLik(x)
## 'log Lik.' -96.01663 (df=3)
```

This is really puzzling. Anyone knows why?

---

**Edit1: `glm` examples by @crayfish44**

```
model.g <- glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family=gaussian)
logLik(model.g) # df=3
model.p <- glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family=poisson)
logLik(model.p) #df=2
model.G <- glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family=Gamma)
logLik(model.G) #df=3
```

---

**Edit2: methods of `logLik`**

```
> methods(logLik)
[1] logLik.Arima*  logLik.glm*  logLik.lm*  logLik.logLik* logLik.nls*
```

Comment: Yes exactly. A linear model.

Comment: Right. And it returns: -151.14 (df=4). Which is the right value. The problem is in the dof. There are 4 dof's  when clearly there are only 3 parameters to be estimated: one constant and two slope parameters.

Comment: I gave it the same name =)

Comment: Right thx for the changes. Looks much more readable.

Comment: `model.g <- glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family=gaussian)` 
`model.p <- glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family=poisson)` 
`model.G <- glm(dist ~ speed, cars, family=Gamma)` 
`logLik(model.g) #df=3`  
`logLik(model.p) #df=2` 
`logLik(model.G) #df=3` I guess +1 is sd (family=gaussian), Dispersion parameter (family=Gamma).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were actually really close to the answer, when we decided to inspect `stats:::logLik.lm`. Had we further inspect `stats:::logLik.glm` *(Thanks to the glm example by @crayfish44: Mate, you are awesome. Once again you give me inspiration, since the last post regarding `persp()` and `trans3d()`. Thanks!)*, we would have solved the issue.

The pitfall of using `:::`, is that we are unable to view comments for the code. So I've decided to check the source file of R-3.3.0. You can open the file `R-3.3.0/src/library/stats/R/logLik.R` to view commented code for generic functions `logLik.**`.

```
## log-likelihood for glm objects
logLik.glm <- function(object, ...)
{
    if(!missing(...)) warning("extra arguments discarded")
    fam <- family(object)$family
    p <- object$rank
    ## allow for estimated dispersion
    if(fam %in% c("gaussian", "Gamma", "inverse.gaussian")) p <- p + 1
    val <- p - object$aic / 2
    ## Note: zero prior weights have NA working residuals.
    attr(val, "nobs") <- sum(!is.na(object$residuals))
    attr(val, "df") <- p
    class(val) <- "logLik"
    val
 }
```

Note the lines:

```
p <- object$rank
## allow for estimated dispersion
if(fam %in% c("gaussian", "Gamma", "inverse.gaussian")) p <- p + 1
```

`p` is the effect number of model coefficients after rank-detection.

- When we have `"gaussian()"`, `"Gamma()"` and `"inverse.gaussian()"` response, the degree of freedom is added 1, as we need the estimation of dispersion parameter of exponential distribution.
- For "`binomial()`" and "`poisson()`" response, the dispersion parameter is known to be 1, hence needs not be estimated.

Maybe `?logLik` should consider explaining this, in case there are some ones as foolish as we are!

Comment: So the plus 1 comes from estimation of the standart deviatio? I was suspectin something like this.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: FWIW `?logLik.lm` does have a (slightly oblique) note: 'For ‘"lm"’ fits it is assumed that the scale has been estimated (by maximum likelihood or REML)'